# Inserting new line break while writing on PPT using PHPPowerPoint

Tags: newline, line-breaks, phppowerpoint

I am creating a PPT using PHPPowerPoint with the data imported from database. Everything is going perfect just I want to insert New line/line breaks between some of the data. Nothing is helpful, can anyone please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `PHP_EOL` constant does the trick.